# returning 204 No Content through WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Are there any known issues surrounding returning 204 No Content through API Manager?

Looking at the timing of the packets on the wire from APIManager, it looks like for other requests, APIManager waits for the client to acknowledge receipt of the packets making up the response, and then proceeds to close the connection, whereas for a 204 response, it immediately closes the connection, before the client has acknowledged receipt of anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such known issue.
What is the version that you are using and what are the configurations you done?

Comment: Version 1.3.  It seems API Manager adds "0\r\n" as the body of the response when we are trying to return 204 No Content through API Manager.  Do you know what causes this, or how to turn it off?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your scenario & the configurations done?

Comment: Our configuration is very simple.  Mostly out of the box API Manager.  We are simply publishing a REST API that will return 204 No Content on a successful DELETE operation.  SOAP UI and CURL error out trying to read the 204 No Content, and we've done a TCP trace and figured out that API Manager is adding "0\r\n" as the body of the response.  Is there any specific configuration you are wondering about?  As I said, it is almost 100% out of the box API Manager.  No other WSO2 components yet.

Comment: Sorry, We have identified this as an issue in the API Manager. Could you please open a new "JIRA" (https://wso2.org/jira/‎), stating your problem. That will help all the parties to track the status of the issue.

Comment: I don't have a login on wso2.org/jira.  How do I get one?

Comment: Thanks, We will look into this ASAP

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense when the API Manager 204 it means it doesn't expect any content from the Back-end service hence the connection is closed immediately.